# Is This Actually Ambiguous?

Tags: c++, nested, initializer-list, ambiguous, list-initialization

So I am aware that braces in code can mean more than just an `initializer_list`: [What Is a Curly-Brace Enclosed List If Not an intializer_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37682392/2642059)

But what should they *default* to?

For example, say that I define an overloaded function:

```
void foo(const initializer_list<int>& row_vector) { cout << size(row_vector) << "x1 - FIRST\n"; }
void foo(const initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>& matrix) { cout << size(matrix) << 'x' << size(*begin(matrix)) << " - SECOND\n"; }
```

If I call `foo({ 1, 2, 3 })` the 1<sup>st</sup> will obviously be called. And if I call `foo({ { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } })` the 2<sup>nd</sup> will obviously be called.

But what if I call:

```
foo({ { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } })
```

Are those nested braces `int`-initializers or `initializer_list<int>` intializers? [gcc says it's ambiguous](http://ideone.com/3DsWe7) But if you take that code and run it on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ Visual Studio says it's just constructing an `initializer_list<int>`. Who's right? Should there be a default here?

Comment: It's ambiguous, because I don't know which is right. If a human can't know, what hope could a compiler have?

Comment: Both `int i = {42};` and `std::initializer_list<int> ini = { 42 };` are correct [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/704c8ce1864b1c3e). So it is ambiguous.

Comment: @MooingDuck This is probably my misconception, but apart from list initialization I thought we had to specify what type we were initializing. Not just do `{ 1 }`, I thought we had to do `int{ 1 }`. If that's the case Visual Studio seems to make the most sense.

Comment: @JonathanMee: That's not the case, you don't have to specify the type. `{{1}}` can match `init_list<int>`, or `init_list<init_list<int>>`, [or even `std::array<char,1>`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa558cf25155c0e1), depending on the context.

Comment: @MooingDuck `cout << { 1 } << endl` is illegal for example. Even though there is an insertion operator for `int`s. in my mind if you haven't directly specified the type it shouldn't be a constructor. Obviously initialization does that and obviously `int{ 1 }` does that, but `{ 1 }` doesn't in my mind. I think of that as a `initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: That's illegal not because there isn't a conversion, but because the grammar prevents you from writing a braced-init-list there.

Comment: @T.C. That really helps me clarify. So you're saying that anywhere I would be able to initialize an `intializer_list<int>` I would be equally eligible to initialize an `int`, and since there is no preferred conversion this is ambiguous.

Comment: @Jonathan No, and that isn't true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is in [[over.ics.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list):

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is `std::initializer_list<X>` and all the elements of the initializer list can be implicitly converted to `X`, the implicit conversion sequence is the worst conversion necessary to convert an element of the list to `X`, or if the initializer list has no elements, the identity conversion.

In both your overloads, the worst conversion necessary is the identity conversion. So we have two implicit conversion sequences with rank identity. There is a rule in [[over.match.best]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3) which prefers a list-initialization of a `std::initializer_list<X>` over alternatives (so `std::initializer_list<int>` is preferred to `int` for `{1}`), but there nothing to suggest that this rule should apply recursively.

Since there's nothing to disambiguate the two conversion sequences, the call is ambiguous. gcc and clang are correct to reject.

Comment: I'm kinda curious about whether MS decided that as it doesn't specify whether the rule applies recursively, it would be safest to treat it as such unless and until it was otherwise stated, or if they just messed something up.

Comment: I think this warrants a CWG issue, as applying that rule recursively seems more useful.

Comment: @bogdan I [posted](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/2VUQYjJ-8Bk) about it. People seem justifiably more interested in `enable_shared_from_this` :)